# Android Picasso library only caches files in memory

Tags: android, picasso

I am initializing Picasso like this:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this) 
                 .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this)) 
                 .build(); 
picasso.setDebugging(true);
```

Somehow, if the images only get saved to the memory cache, never to the disk cache. Closing the app and reopening it causes the images to get re-downloaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need the custom downloader? Whats the behaviour if you skip that?

Comment: Same behavior. Seems you have to provide a custom implementation for this. I ended up reverting Universal Image Loader for now.

Comment: Salut Vlad, did you ever figure it out? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: The response headers depict whether the result will be stored on disk or not. Try looking at the response and see if it does that.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you don't have any special thing to add, create Picasso like below:

```
Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(this);
```

It reuses the instance instead of creating a new one each time (which is specially dangerous if you're calling it from an Adapter.getView()). So use the Picasso.Builder only when it's really necessary to customize some behavior, like providing a different Downloader or Listener and if you do so, don't do it from a Adapter.getView() implementation.

You don't need to provide the **OkHttpDownloader**, it is already provided by default if you have OkHttp library in the classpath. Check if the URLs you're downloading from are not suffering any Http Redirects, like HTTP 301 or HTTP 302, Picasso doesn't deal well with it in some cases, at least until the current version (2.2.0).

Apart from that, your code looks fine and should work. Good luck!